# .NET converting simple arrays to List Generics

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics, clr

I have an array of any type `T` (`T[]`) and I want to convert it into a List generic (`List<T>`). Is there any other way apart from creating a Generic list, traversing the whole array and adding the element in the List?

**Present Situation:**

```
string[] strList = {"foo","bar","meh"};
List<string> listOfStr = new List<string>();
foreach(string s in strList)
{
    listOfStr.Add(s);
}
```

**My ideal situation:**

```
string[] strList = {"foo","bar","meh"};
List<string> listOfStr = strList.ToList<string>();
```

**Or:**

```
string[] strList = {"foo","bar","meh"};
List<string> listOfStr = new List<string>(strList);
```

I am suggesting the last 2 method names as I think compiler or `CLR` can perform some optimizations on the whole operations if It want inbuilt.

P.S.: I am not talking about the `Array` or `ArrayList` Type

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, one of the code segment you have will work. In C#, string needs to be enclosed in double quote, not single.

```
string[] strList = {"foo","bar","meh"};
List<string> listOfStr = new List<string>(strList);
```

Comment: Yea, I do this all the time... well, sometimes.

Comment: Sorry for the quote mistake. I Fixed it now.

Comment: This doesn't need LINQ and is the simplest technique.

Comment: Pratik, without Linq - `new List<string>(strList)` is not allowed. It accepts only an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` (IIRC)

Comment: Array implements IEnumerable<T> since .NET 2.0

Answer (score 10):

If you reference `System.Linq`, you can type:

```
string[] strList = {'foo','bar','meh'}; 
List<string> listOfStr = strList.ToList();
```

exactly like you want to.

The second syntax should also work.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
using System.Linq;

string[] strList = {'foo','bar','meh'};
List<string> listOfStr = strList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
object[] array = new object[10];
List<object> list = array.ToList();
```

Method ToList is linq method. You need to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a List, or will an IList work for you? Because the CLR (has special code to) support casting of arrays to generic collection interfaces, simply:

```
string[] strList = {"foo","bar","meh"};
IList<string> listOfStr = (IList<string>)strList;
```